# d3js , enterprise counterpart - for .NET?

Tags: .net, data-binding, d3.js, data-visualization

Are there any Microsoft products similar to d3.js ? 
A visualization tool for data, which can be used in a .NET framework ? 
Is it possible to customize ms business intelligence software ?

Comment: Are you looking for a `d3.js`-like .NET library for a desktop application?

Comment: Yes ... where I can visualize data according to my function using the library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.net has a built in charting library [chart controls on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456632%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

But from what I understand it's not really like d3 in the sense that it's a selection of built in controls not necessarily like d3 for building bespoke visualisations.

[Scott Hannlseman has a blog post discussing ILNumerics](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GeneratingComplexMathVisualizationsInSVGUsingCAndILNumerics.aspx) which looks more like a toolkit for building visualisations.

Regarding general charting libraries there are lots and lots, but seeing as you're looking for d3.js counterparts I'm guessing you're looking for bespoke visualisations.

Comment: Hi @user3355665 if this is the answer you are looking for, please feel free to mark it as answered :-)

Comment: Alex it helped me conceptually , and I dont see the answered button...I'm new to stackoverflow. can u help me with that ?

Comment: Thanks @user3355665 glad it helped, it looks like it's marked as answered now (maybe someone else did it), thanks.

Comment: I did it .... wanted to edit my previous comment but couldn't as it had lesser characters. clicked on the tick icon :)